# What was the nature of the tax of 32 people?

Tags: army-military-war, mattos, taxes

BeMidbar 31:40 states that, after the war with the Midyanim, in which Bnei Yisrael were instructed to take captives and booty, and to pay taxes to HaShem from this plunder, they "paid" a total of thirty-two (32) people.

What does that mean? Were the captives enslaved? Did they perform work in the Mishkan? What was their status and what became of them?

Comment: IIRC, they were, in fact, made slaves, but to whom specifically remains unclear to me. Kohanim, maybe? Perhaps they were sold at a premium like other objects owned by the BhM...